# MYSQL: Using outer alias in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display a list of payments made on transactions and show the current balance after each payment.

**EDIT:**
Here is my schema and sample data
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77dcc6/1

Below is an example of expected result

```
number  date        total   paid    balance
1      2018-01-01   1000    1000    0
2      2018-01-02   1250    1000    250
2      2018-01-05   1250    250     0
3      2018-01-03   2500    2000    500
3      2018-01-07   2500    300     200
3      2018-01-08   2500    200     0
5      2018-01-07   2149    2149    0
```

This is my initial try but the total payment is calculated based on sum of ALL transaction payments. What I want is the sum of payments relative to the current `p` payment row

```
select
    t.number,
    DATE(p.date) 'date',
    ti.total 'total',
    SUM(p.amount) 'paid',
    ti.total - paid.total 'balance'
from payments p
left join transactions t
on p.transaction_id = t.id
left join (
    select inner_ti.transaction_id, sum((inner_ti.price - inner_ti.discount) * inner_ti.quantity)  'total'
    from transaction_items inner_ti
    group by inner_ti.transaction_id
) ti on t.id = ti.transaction_id
left join (
    select inner_p.transaction_id, sum(inner_p.amount) 'total'
    from payments inner_p
    group by inner_p.transaction_id
) paid on t.id = paid.transaction_id
group by t.number, DATE(p.date), ti.total, paid.total
order by t.number, DATE(p.date) ASC
```

then I thought I could just put where clause in the `paid` to sum only the payments relative to `p.date`, but I got an error `unknown column p.date`

```
select
    t.number,
    DATE(p.date),
    ti.total 'total',
    SUM(p.amount) 'paid',
    ti.total - paid.total 'balance'
from payments p
left join transactions t
on p.transaction_id = t.id
left join (
    select inner_ti.transaction_id, sum((inner_ti.price - inner_ti.discount) * inner_ti.quantity)  'total'
    from transaction_items inner_ti
    group by inner_ti.transaction_id
) ti on t.id = ti.transaction_id
left join (
    select inner_p.transaction_id, sum(inner_p.amount) 'total'
    from payments inner_p
    where inner_p.date <= p.date -- error unknown column p.date
    group by inner_p.transaction_id
) paid on t.id = paid.transaction_id
group by t.number, DATE(p.date), ti.total, paid.total
order by DATE(p.date) ASC
```

*Please note that I'm grouping by `p.date` since we are concern on payments made within the day.*

Can someone please enlighten me why I'm getting that error? And is there any workaround to achieve the expected result?

Thank you!

Comment: `p.date` is not available in the subquery.  But I'm not sure how to fix your query logically.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry thanks. I updated it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should start again

```
drop table if exists p,t,ti;

create table t(id int,number int);
create table ti(id int,tid int, price int);
create table p(id int,tid int,dt date, paid int);

insert into t values (1,1355),(2,1359),(3,1361);
insert into ti values (1,1,400),(2,1,200),(3,1,299),(4,2,4045),(5,3,1500),(6,3,40),(7,3,8);
insert into p values (1,1,'2018-01-01',200),(2,1,'2018-01-01',250),(3,1,'2018-02-01',449),
                            (4,2,'2018-01-01',1515),(5,2,'2018-02-01',35),
                            (6,3,'2018-01-06',1548);

select t.id,number,p.dt paiddate,(select sum(price) from ti where ti.tid = t.id) due,
        sum(p.paid) paid,
        ifnull((Select sum(p1.paid) from p p1 where p1.dt < p.dt and p1.tid = p.tid),0) +   sum(p.paid) aggsumpaid,
        (select sum(price) from ti where ti.tid = t.id) - 
        (ifnull((Select sum(p1.paid) from p p1 where p1.dt < p.dt and p1.tid = p.tid),0) +  sum(p.paid)) runningbal
from t 
left join p on p.tid = t.id
group by t.id,number,p.dt
```

Result

```
+------+--------+------------+------+------+------------+------------+
| id   | number | paiddate   | due  | paid | aggsumpaid | runningbal |
+------+--------+------------+------+------+------------+------------+
|    1 |   1355 | 2018-01-01 |  899 |  450 |        450 |        449 |
|    1 |   1355 | 2018-02-01 |  899 |  449 |        899 |          0 |
|    2 |   1359 | 2018-01-01 | 4045 | 1515 |       1515 |       2530 |
|    2 |   1359 | 2018-02-01 | 4045 |   35 |       1550 |       2495 |
|    3 |   1361 | 2018-01-06 | 1548 | 1548 |       1548 |          0 |
+------+--------+------------+------+------+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```